# How to do this vloop in excel

Tags: excel, ms-office, spreadsheet, office-2007, vba

I have one excel file with 2 sheets WorkSheet and ReviewSheet

WorkSheet data is as below

```
Employee Name       Project       Work Status      Date
-------------       -------       -----------      ----------
abc                 123           Holiday          01/12/2011
abc                 456           Sick             02/12/2011
```

ReviewSheet data is as Below

```
          01/12/2011     02/12/2011
          ----------     ----------
abc       123            456
```

Consider The above as sample data.
I manage to do the VLOOKUP to link the Project name of WorkSheet  to ReviewSheet. Any changes of Project name in WorkSheet will change the project name of the ReviewSheet.

I am now trying to change the cell's colour of Project name   of ReviewSheet based on the work status of the WorkSheet. For example -> *(WorkSheet)* ***abc*** who work in project ***123*** is on ***holiday*** at ***01/12/2011***. This will change *(ReviewSheet)* the colour of the cell of project ***123*** at ***01/12/2011*** to ***yellow*** .

How can I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with conditional formatting (In 2003, Format --> Conditional Formatting...). Choose the "Formula Is" and use the same `VLOOKUP` formula as you used on your ReviewSheet, except that it should refer to the "Work status" column instead of the "Project" column of your WorkSheet.

Example:

Formula Is... `=VLOOKUP({as described above})="Holiday"`

and set Format... Patterns to yellow.